# Problema en NodeJS: TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

sé que esta pregunta la hicieron muchas veces, pero sinceramente no encuentro la respuesta. Soy novato, aclaro. Con otros proyectos no tenía problema y ahora cada proyecto que creo que salta este problema. El código es básico:

```js
const express=require('express');
const path=require('path');

const app= express();
const routes=require('./routes/index');

//settings
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

//middlewares
app.use(express.json);
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

//routes
app.use(routes);

//static fields
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

//start server
app.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
    console.log('Server on port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

El package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  }
}
```

y el error:

TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
    at Function.use (C:\Users\nestor\Desktop\node\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210:11)
    at Object. (C:\Users\nestor\Desktop\node\app.js:17:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)

El módulo index.js:

```js
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.end('Hola mundo');
})

exports.module=router;
```

Comment: ¿ Puedes mostrar el `module.exports` de tu archivo `./routes/index.js` ?

Comment: Hola, ahí lo acabo de hacer. Me olvidé aclarar que al quitar  const routes=require('./routes/index');  y app.use('routes') el problema desaparece.

Comment: jejeje ... claro, porque tu problema está en el `./routes/index.js`. Si no lo usas, no hay problema :-)

Comment: Perdón, soy novato en nodejs, estoy mandando solamente un "hola mundo" por qué no ha de funcionar? o sea, lo estoy usando.

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo: el error era en exports.module y en realidad es module.exports. Gracias Trauma y gracias al muchacho que me ayudó.